# How to get all tables names in SQL CE database?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have a database in SQL CE (sdf file) and I need to get all names of the tables.

How to do it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where TABLE_TYPE <> 'VIEW'
```